# CiviSEPA payment page asking for credit card informations

Tags: civisepa

I updated CiviCRM to 4.4.19 and the civisepa module through git. Since then, instead of the BIC/IBAN informations required for SEPA payments, the contribution page displays a non-functioning credit card selector:

[image: non-functioning credit card selector]

I cannot find anything wrong in the payment processor config, which is correctly set as sepa_dd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the existing payment processor had the wrong payment_type (historical reasons) and civicrm didn't display the direct debit block but defaulted to the "dummy card" one.

Changing the payment processor type to direct debit (2) solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

@Ash_crow, I haven't encountered this problem yet.

Could you please go ahead and create a ticket on https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/issues? Could you also add some more information (like your CiviSEPA version and the setup of your contribution page)?

Comment: Sure, I'll create the ticket right now!

Comment: Here: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/issues/343

Comment: Great, thanks. We'll deal with this problem there.